# Organize file by Linux

Tags: linux, file, awk

I want to thank the great help and support. Well, I have the following file:

```
name   id alello chr    pos snp    
s1     215     a    1   11  a215    
s1     216     a    1   11  a216    
s1     217     a    1   11  a217    
s1     218     a    1   11  a218    
s2     215     b    2   22  b215    
s2     216     b    2   22  b216    
s2     217     b    2   22  b217    
s2     218     b    2   22  b218
```

and I need that file be this way:

```
snp allelo  chr pos 215     216      217    218    
s1     a    1   11  a215    a216    a217    a218    
s2     b    2   22  b215    b216    b217    b218
```

Please, someone can help me? Thank you very much

Comment: Thank u for edit my question, Jas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR==1{h=$1 OFS $3 OFS $4 OFS $5; next} 
            {a[$1]=(($1 in a)?(a[$1] OFS $NF):($3 OFS $4 OFS $5 OFS $6));
             if(!($2 in b)) {h=h OFS $2; b[$2]}} 
        END{print h; for(k in a) print k,a[k]}' file | column -t

name  alello  chr  pos  215   216   217   218
s1    a       1    11   a215  a216  a217  a218
s2    b       2    22   b215  b216  b217  b218
```

Comment: Hi man, thank u. But don't work, a error message appears. line 2: $:command not found

Comment: Thank u very much.

Comment: for header, change `NR==1{h=$1` to `NR==1{h="snp"`

Comment: I wrong in my file, dude. It was "name" rather than "snp" in output, but you did correct.. thanks...

Comment: I think I saw wrong, the columns alello, chr and pos are not printed!
Do you hava a sugestion?

Comment: Well, I used the same input file as posted.  Did you copy/paste the code correctly?  Can you try again with the same data file posted?  There is no `gawk` extensions used.  I'll be surprised if any `awk` version doesn't support this code.  Also you can try changing `$3` in the code with `"XXX"` for debugging and see whether it appears in the output.

Comment: Man, very strange, everything seemed normal, but now crashed. I'm sure that had given all right, when tested in this smaller database, but when I used another larger database did not work, and when I came to this example the database did not work. It is possible that my pc has given error?

Comment: Man, I change my pc... And so, it's works again.. jesuizz

Comment: You should state that the output order is "random" and so the `s2` line could come out before the `s1` line, etc.

Comment: I solve this installing gwak. The command works now. Thank u.

Comment: There is nothing in that script that would require gawk rather than any other awk.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR == 1     { hdr = $1 OFS $3 OFS $4 OFS $5; next }
!seen[$2]++ { hdr = hdr OFS $2 }

$1 != prev  {
    if (++numRows > 1) {
        if (numRows == 2) {
            print hdr
        }
        print row
    }
    row = $1 OFS $3 OFS $4 OFS $5
}
{ row = row OFS $6; prev = $1 }
END { print row }

$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -t
name  alello  chr  pos  215   216   217   218
s1    a       1    11   a215  a216  a217  a218
s2    b       2    22   b215  b216  b217  b218
```

Note that this will output the rows in the order they appear in the input and it only stores one row in memory at a time so it will work well no matter how large your input file is.

Comment: Thank u, but I could not run. Many errors appear:
./tr.sh: line 3: NR: command not found 
./tr.sh: line 3: next: command not found
./tr.sh: line 4: !seen[]++: command not found
./tr.sh: line 6: !=: command not found
./tr.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
./tr.sh: line 8: `}'
If u can help, I'll be very grateful. 


They may seem silly mistakes, but I am a layman and I can not fix.

Comment: Without seeing your script it's hard for me to debug it but at a **GUESS** maybe you put the awk script into a file named `tr.sh` and then tried to execute it as `./tr.sh file` instead of `awk -f tr.sh file`. Awk is not shell, awk is a tool you call from shell with it's own syntax and semantics.